# Difference between BX & [BX] registers. And what are their sizes in bits?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors

How here they mention that [BX] is 8 bit? means byte

[image]

Comment: CL is an 8-bit register, so the instruction knows to only move one byte from the memory address that is stored in _BX_. _BX_ is the value in the _BX_ register. _[BX]_ is the value at the address pointed to by _BX_.

Answer (score 5):

`BX` is the `BX` register -- a 16-bit register.  `[BX]` is the contents of the memory pointed at by the `BX` register.  So any instruction that uses `[BX]` uses the 16-bit value in the `BX` register AS AN ADDRESS and reads memory at that address.

How much memory?  Well it depends on the instruction, but in the example, it's an 8-bit move instruction, so 8 bits (one byte).